# Sometimes getting an issue to type in atom (text editor)

Tags: atom-editor

sometimes I'm getting this issue where I can't type in the atom text editor. The problem can be fixed by spamming keys for about a second then I can begin to type again, but it's beginning to get really annoying and I might just switch editors again.

Basically, sometimes when I'm writing my code the flashing insertion cursor just becomes a block, when I press a key it disappears and with another keypress it reappears like it's expecting me to insert something.

Anyone else had this issue, if so how do I solve it? Thanks!

EDIT:

[image: atom error]

It happened again :(

SOLUTION:

Press the "a" key fixes this.

Comment: I have had a similar issue, were I can't type numbers in HTML files.

Comment: It's driving me crazy because as soon as I delve in and start writing some stuff all of a sudden I can't write stuff. Usually happens when I click on a classname or highlight a certain word to change it.

Comment: Are you using vim-mode?